# Difference in std::regex_replace behaviour between GCC and MSVC

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm trying to implement a method to escape a string for use with a regex match.

Unfortunately, I'm finding an inconsistency between compilers.  This code (with added boost implementation for comparison) produces different results when compiled with GCC 7.1 and Visual Studio 2015U3:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

std::string regexEscape(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::regex_replace(s, std::regex{ R"([\^\.\$\|\{\}\(\)\[\]\*\+\?\/\\])" }, std::string{ R"(\\\1&)" }, std::regex_constants::match_default | std::regex_constants::format_sed);
}

std::string boostRegexEscape(const std::string& s)
{
    return boost::regex_replace(s, boost::regex{ R"([\^\.\$\|\{\}\(\)\[\]\*\+\?\/\\])" }, std::string{ R"(\\\1&)" }, boost::match_default | boost::format_sed);
}

int main()
{
    std::string test{ R"(123.456^789$123\456|789*123+456(789)123?456)" };
    std::cout << regexEscape(test) << '\n';
    std::cout << boostRegexEscape(test) << '\n';
}
```

GCC:

```
123\\.456\\^789\\$123\\\456\\|789\\*123\\+456\\(789\\)123\\?456
123\.456\^789\$123\\456\|789\*123\+456\(789\)123\?456
```

MSVC:

```
123\.456\^789\$123\\456\|789\*123\+456\(789\)123\?456
123\.456\^789\$123\\456\|789\*123\+456\(789\)123\?456
```

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: I think you need [`std::regex_replace(s, std::regex{ R"(([.^$|{}()[\]*+?/\\]))" }, std::string{ R"(\$1)" }, std::regex_constants::match_default);`](http://rextester.com/VODJV79834), and the same should work in Boost.

Comment: Boost is already doing the right thing - the question is about the difference in results between compilers.

Comment: But the compilers *are* different. Boost uses Boost (a variation of a PCRE) and std::regex is based on various types of engines, the default is ECMAScript 5. In boost replacement, two literal backslashes actually denote 1 backslash and in `std::regex`, that makes 2 literal backslashes. That is the difference and is expected.

Comment: Yes, and GCC/MSVC give different results for exactly the same code.  So why are GCC/MSVC different?  They look to produce identical results for the replacement you've offered (which is great, thank you!), but perform differently in my example.

Comment: So, the first comment snippet works the same across the two engines, right?

Comment: It does - and across compilers, which is excellent.  The question is still open - why does my example perform differently across compilers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked the regex engines to replace with `R"(\\\1&)"`, a `\\\1&` substitution pattern treating it as a [`sed` replacement pattern](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03). In sed, `&` stands for the whole match. As there is no group with ID 1 in the pattern the `\1` refers to an empty string. The first two backslashes are 2 literal backslashes in a raw string literal when parsed with the `std::regex_replace`.

When you use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/sed_format.html), the first two backslashes are parsed as a single backslash, a literal backslash in a Boost replacement pattern must be escaped in order to use a single literal backslash as a replacement:

> Sed-style format strings treat all characters as literals except:
>
> `&` The ampersand character is replaced in the output stream by the the whole of what matched the regular expression. Use \& to output a literal '&' character.
>
> `\` **Specifies an escape sequence.**

Regarding the rest of the replacement pattern, it will work the same.

You may use

```
 std::regex_replace(s, std::regex{ R"(([.^$|{}()[\]*+?/\\]))" }, std::string{ R"(\$1)" }, std::regex_constants::match_default);
```

With Boost, equivalent method/options can be used to achieve consistency in the results. Here, the default engines are used.

Regarding the MSVC and GCC differences, the documentation about that is scarce. It is clear that defining a literal backslash behavior is different between the two mentioned compiler. Note that a lot of regex libraries treat a literal backslash as a regex escape (same as in Boost, see reference above), and to define a literal replacement backslash, you need to double a literal backslash in the replacement pattern. The engine you used in GCC is [ECMAScript](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript).

**It seems that how a backlash replacement pattern should be defined is left to each regex replace implementation**. When you use it with GCC, a single literal `\` (= `"\\"`) is treated as a single literal replacement backslash. MSVC compiler decided to go with the majority of the regex engines and - which makes sense as you can use replacement backreferences as `\1`-`\9` when using `std::regex_constants::format_sed` - requires  a literal replacement backslash to be escaped and to replace with a single `\`, you need to use two literal backslashes, `"\\\\"` (or `R"(\\)"`).

Comment: This is excellent, but the question is about why the same code performs differently when compiled using GCC vs MSVC. If anything, this raises yet another question about why they perform the same using this code, and differently using mine.

Comment: @DaveM Ok, let me check further. I still have an impression it has been already posted though  I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: There seem to be plenty of questions about boost::regex_replace vs std::regex_replace, but I couldn't find anything about std::regex_replace performing differently between compilers - hence the new question :)

Comment: I think that's as close as we'll get to a full answer, thank you!  I'm a little surprised that something like that should be left to the implementation to define?

Comment: @DaveM Well, replacement patterns are less "regex engine regulated" regex domain. Regex engines themselves are mostly about how to find specific texts while various tools and languages provide their own features to replace found strings with other strings.